# Migrating from EXT JS 3.2.0 to EXT JS 6.0.0

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I'm try to migrate to the new version 6.0.0, but In the application developed in 3.2.0 I find that it use a plugin called CheckColumn, to add a column with check boxes to a grid. How can i implement this funtionality in the new version (6.0.0)?

Please help me.

Thanks,
Sofy

Comment: If it's a very large app, it might be beneficial to try and get the app to version 4 first, and then using the [Upgrade Advisor](https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/upgradeadviser/) to point out any other upgrade issues.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

`CheckColumn` implemented in [CheckboxModel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel.html).

You must change [selModel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.panel.Table.html#cfg-selModel) to it on you `grid`.

```
...
selModel: {
     selType: 'checkboxmodel'
},
...
```